# Is it possible to change the type of just one column in a numpy array created from genfromtxt?

Tags: python, django, numpy, types, genfromtxt

I'm creating a numpy array which then will be exported into a django model. As dtype attribute I have a None, but I have one column which should be an integer which admits NULL values. Now, when in the csv a 'NULL' string is found, the type of that column is changed in bool, which doesn't admit a None.

Now, is it possible to do something like `dtype={'name of the columns', 'int'}` just for that column and make the rest be still on None and let numpy decide the type?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about genfromtxt, you can set the dtype using the dtype parameter:

e.g.

If your file contains

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
1.0 2.0 3.0 hello
```

Then

```
a=np.genfromtxt('vlen.txt',dtype=[('col0', 'i4'), ('col1', '<f8'), ('col2', '<f8'), ('col3', 'S5')])

a['col0']
array([1, 1, 1, 1]) # note ints not floats
```

Comment: I was wondering if I have to write a tuple for every column or if I can just define one, and leave the others to numpy. In the end I solved with pandas.